# What features are disabled when you log in to someone's account using the Grant Login feature?

Tags: grant-login

I'm logged in to a customer's org (Professional edition) and wanted to check some things using the new query editor - however, it's not in the developer console. My only options are Logs and Repository. UPDATE: I logged in to an Enterprise customer's org and query editor WAS available so maybe this particular issue is more related to Professional vs Enterprise?

I also noticed that I can't login to a different user's account if that user has granted access to admins to login to their account. We get reports that a specific user is having issues but are granted access to the admin's account who has access to log in to the user's account. It sounds like that doesn't really work.

What other options/features are disabled for app developers when they get access to a customer's account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have an exhaustive list, so I've made this a Community wiki so people can more easily add to this list.

Without further ado, a list of what I have seen:

- Reset Password/Security Token
- Export a Report (Running is still ok)
- Grant Login Access
- Use "Login As" again (go deeper) even if user can do it normally

Comment: Daniel, you sure about the exporting reports? Works OK for me (but I've tried as regular admin, I'm not an external app developer)

Comment: I am, I just double checked

Comment: I'm able to export reports if I log on as another user. That is a permission on the profile, so maybe the person you are logging in on doesn't have that permission? But as @eyescream says, I'm a regular admin and not an external app developer.

Comment: @DanielHoechst this is **not** a list relating to "Login As" It is actions that are unavailable when logging in using the License Management App's subscriber management