# When logged into an org via the Subscriber's tab, why can't I see the the printable view / export to excel option on a report?

Tags: managed-package, reporting, data-export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What features are disabled when you log in to someone’s account using the Grant Login feature?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4122/what-features-are-disabled-when-you-log-in-to-someones-account-using-the-grant)

As a Salesforce ISV Partner, when logged into a salesforce customer's org via the Subscriber's tab in our ISV Business Org, why can't I see the the printable view / export to excel option on a standard report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user grants login access to you through a managed package and you access the org from the Subscriber tab available to ISV Partners, I found that the data export options are no longer available.

If you login directly to the org with an active user account, you should see the buttons for 'Printable View' and 'Export Details' on the report.  If you don't see them, you will need to confirm that the profile for the user account has the System Permission of 'Export Reports'.